# What happens when sending to a Python Connection while memory is full?

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I am designing a system of pipes between several processes in Python and I am concerned about the behavior of a Connection when the memory is full.

Say that I have process A (faster) processing input data and process B (slower) consuming A's output and thus releasing some memory space. If the memory is full when A writes to the [Pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) between A and B what happens in:

1. The write is delayed until some more space is available.
2. An OOM exception is raised.

If 1, how can it be configured? If 2, is the exception local to A or does the whole system crash?